# Summation toy problem makes no sense to me

Tags: javascript, math

```
let names = ["Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard"]
whoIsNext = (names, r) => names[r-1] || whoIsNext(names, Math.round((r-names.length)/2))}

whoIsNext(names, 41) === "Sheldon"
whoIsNext(names, 7230702951) === "Leonard"
```

OK this was a simple problem where r is the number of cokes in a machine and names is an
array of people in line. They are the only people in line, no different people people can be
added. So when the first person "Sheldon gets a coke from the limited coke machine, He then goes to the end of the line and he doubles. That's right there are now two"Sheldon"'s at the end of the line. the next person does the same thing and so on until there is only one coke left. The person who gets the last coke gets returned. Now I found one answer

```
function whoIsNext(names, r){
    let name = names.shift()
    if(r === 1) {
        return name
    }  
    names = names.concat(name, name)
    return whoIsNext(names, --r)
}
```

That works with small numbers of coke, up to around 37,000 the I start getting blown stack errors. But when i use the first solution it works perfect every time.

Can some one please explain why the first solution works. It doesnt add anything to the end of the array it just does some tricky math that I cant quit follow or comprehend why it works i just know it does. And its driving me crazy!!!

Comment: Instead of doubling the individuals, they're cutting the number of cokes in half on each iteration (those are equivalent operations). When the number of cokes is less than the number of people in line, the result becomes a simple index lookup.

Comment: Yes thats what I'm sayinging, but it works. I think it might be a summation math trick but I'm not "that" great at Math.

Comment: I'm not great at Math either, but if you think about the problem as a ratio of people to cokes, then doubling the people is essentially the same as halving the cokes. So subtract the current number of people from the cokes *(give each one a coke)*, and then the people double, which is the same as the available cokes being halved. So on the next recursive call, you can still give each person in the list *(which hasn't changed in length)* a single coke, because you cut the available cokes in half.

Comment: ...Another way that doesn't double the people, but may seem more intuitive, would be to add another argument to the function, which tracks the allotment of cokes per person. So it starts with 1, and on each recursive call you double that number. So the adjustment of cokes becomes `r - (names.length * allotment)`... like this: https://jsfiddle.net/pjv912q4/1/